# WPF ListView Cannot Trigger Selection Changed when only one row

Tags: wpf, listview, selection

I have a listview which has its datasource changed after update of a search textbox.

When I enter search criteria that only returns one row, I am unable to trigger the OnSelectionChanged event The listbox works as expected at any other time.

I have tried changing SelectedItem and SelectedIndex in Code, Clicking aimlessly on the ListView both on and off the row and are at the brink of insanity.

Does anyone know of a solution so that I am able to change the selected item!!  Help Please

The code I want to run (somehow) is:

```
private void lstShedBatch_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
try{               
    if (lstShedBatch.SelectedItem != null && lstShedBatch.SelectedIndex != -1)
     {
       ShedBatch currShedBatch = (ShedBatch)this.ShedBatchView.CurrentItem;
       Window1.ShedBatchId = currShedBatch.ShedBatchId;
       Window1.selectedShedId = currShedBatch.ShedId;

       RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(selectShedBatchClickEvent);
                RaiseEvent(args);
        }
       }
      catch
       {
       }
    }
```

The problem as stated above, is that this event does not get triggered if the number of items in the list =0 or 1.  If there is one record, i want to know what it is and use it to pass variables.

Comment: You can't change the selected item if it's the only item, because there's no other item to select.  What kind of activity are you trying to trigger when the selected item changes?

Comment: I am just trying to get the Selected Item to Pass later.  All I am trying to do is say MyItem = lstView.SelectedItem;

Comment: I solved it by setting the selected item to the .Items.FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then use another trigger. For example TextChanged on your TextBox.